# How to target a nested class in a different sheet with JSS?

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm not actually sure if i am using the proper terminology. Basically i would like to have a file with a component such as:

```js
//Foo.tsx
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  foo:{
    background:'red'
  }
})

const Foo = ()=>{
  const classes = useStyles()
  return <div className={classes.foo}/>
}
```

I would like to override the `.foo` selector, but none of the syntax worked for me:

```js
// Bar.tsx
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  bar:{
    '& $foo':{ //<-- what should i use here, if there is anything that would work at all?
      background:'blue!important'
    }
  }
})
const Bar = ()=>{
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div className={classes.bar}>
      <Foo/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation given [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.9.1-alpha.2) you can try something as following :

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  bar:{
    '& .foo':{ //<-- what should i use here, if there is anything that would work at all?
      background:'blue!important'
    }
  }
})
```

I don't know it will work or not but you can try `dot(.)` instead of `dollar($)`

Comment: "Use $ruleName to reference a local rule within the SAME style sheet" I'm concerned that what i'm trying to do is impossible with JSS? Neither ` $.foo` `$foo` nor `.foo` works :( 

The two different `createUseStyles` are basically two different sheets?